# Null pointer exception when adding an image as icon with NetBeans Gui Builder (auto generated code)

Tags: maven, netbeans, nullpointerexception

Here is the auto-generated code from netbeans:

```
loginButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/group8/view/images/loginbutton.png"))); // NOI18N
```

and this is the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at com.group8.view.Query.initComponents(Query.java:158)
    at com.group8.view.Query.<init>(Query.java:43)
    at com.group8.execution.Execution.main(Execution.java:24)
```

I had this program already working. I decided to try to adapt it so I could apply Spring (trying to learn different things). Im using maven as well for the first time. Been through some tutorials and seem to get a few spring examples to work.

Been moving the images folder all over the place because I thought it could be an issue of packaging. Now I have them where I originally had them in the other program. As a subfolder of where the actual class is. Example: Query is in a package called view and the image is in view.images.loginbutton.png

I dont know if I need to declare the images as a maven dependency? Am I missing something super obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Class.getResource(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)): *"Returns: A `URL` object or `null` if no resource with this name is found".* So, that's where the NPE comes from. The resource is most probably not where it is expected to be.

Does *"As a subfolder of where the actual class is"* mean that you have:

```
src/main/java/com/group8/view/Query.java
src/main/java/com/group8/view/images/loginbutton.png
```

If you're using Maven with its suggested default directory structure the following is more appropriate:

```
src/main/java/com/group8/view/Query.java
src/main/resources/com/group8/view/images/loginbutton.png
```

Comment: Seems like the problem was with where the folder was located. I moved the images folder to the resources folder. Worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help. 

Any resources you could recommend to read more about maven and its packaging rules?

Again thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @KikeSanders I use [Apache Maven Project's page](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) ff, the [Available Plugins page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) ff and [Sonatype's Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html) a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put all images in `src/main/resources`. If you don't have this folder, create it.

Then clean and build your proyect and when you run it, it will work :)

Comment: What does this add to the answer that has been accepted three months prior to your answer?

Comment: thanks it works, seems impossible any other way!